# Books about hyperbolic sets / hyperbolic dynamics

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Can someone recommend me some books (for beginners) about hyperbolic sets on smooth manifolds? Also, some books about hyperbolic sets for dynamical systems.

Thank you!

Comment: You might get an answer if you tell us how much you a;ready know about the three topics you've used for tags.

Comment: I am at the beginning.

Comment: I'd rather ask where are you heading with this knowledge?

Comment: I'm reading "Introduction to modern theory of dynamical systems" by Katok and Hasselblat and I can't understand the proof of the Proposition 6.4.6 (page 265): Let $\Lambda$ be a hyperbolic set for $f : U \to M$. There exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $\Lambda$ such that for any $g$ sufficinetly close to $f$ in $C^1$ topology the invariant set $$\underset{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{\cap} g^n(\overline{V})$$ is hyperbolic.

Comment: The proof in the book omits some explanations and I want to understand the things to complete and understand the proof.

Comment: Maybe you should add particular questions about this proof?

Comment: There are many other unclear proofs . The point is that I have to understand very well the notions involved.

Comment: I would recommend Lan Wen's newish book "Differentiable Dynamical Systems: An introduction to Structural Stability and Hyperbolicity." It's the least terse introduction to hyperbolicity and everything is proven in detail. I am not aware of another text that fills in all the details of, say, the stable manifold theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Chapter III in Eduard Zehnder's book [*Lectures on Dynamical Systems*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lectures_on_Dynamical_Systems.html?id=qva7p5NCayUC).

(I don't know exactly what “for beginners” means in this context, but at least I find that book much easier to read than Katok & Hasselblatt.)